# undefined symbol: vmldExp2

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, f2py

I am using f2py and Intel fortran compiler to wrap some fortran code which calls some math library like `dexp` and `dpow`.

The compilation went smoothly without reporting any err, but when I attempted to run the wrapped python modules, the error prompts up:

> ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/foo.so: undefined symbol: vmldExp2

I switched to gfortran and it seems that the similar problem persists, but for `vmldPow2`.

How can I fix this in the f2py context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the intel `svml` lib has been changed quite a bit, I tried various ways and option/flags but ended up not solving the problem at all, but after I upgraded intel fortran compiler from 9.1 to 12.0, it disappeared and now everything works like a charm.